# Single strongly Typed Partial View for two similar classes of different types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, html-helper, strongly-typed-view

I have a Register Primary View which shows two different types of Addresses  1. Home Address 2. Mailing Address

```
  public class RegisterModel
     {             
        public AddressModel HomeAddress { get; set; }
        public AddressModel MailAddress { get; set; }
     }

public class AddressModel
{
   public string Street1 { get; set; }
   public string Street2 { get; set; }
   public string State   { get; set; }
   public string City    { get; set; }
}
```

**My main Register View is Strongly Typed to RegisterModel as follows**

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.RegisterModel
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
  <div id="form">
    @Html.Action("MyAddressPartial")
    @Html.Action("MyAddressPartial")  
  </div>
}
```

**MyAddressPartialView as follows : -**

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.AddressModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}
 <div id="Address">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Street1 ,new { @id="Street1 "})     
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Street2,new { @id="Street2"})
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.State ,new { @id="State "})
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.City,new { @id="City"})
 </div>
```

**My RegisterController:-**

```
// Have to instantiate the strongly Typed partial view when my form first loads
// and then pass it as parameter to "Register" post action method. 
// As you can see the @Html.Action("MyAddressPartial") above in main    
// Register View calls this.
public ActionResult MyAddressPartial()
{
   return PartialView("MyAddressPartialView", new AddressModel());
}
```

I submit my Main Form to below mentioned action method in same Register Controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model, 
                            AddressModel homeAddress, 
                            AddressModel mailingAddress)
{
       //I want to access homeAddress and mailingAddress contents which should 
       //be different, but as if now it comes same.
}
```

I don't want to create a separate class one for MailingAddress and one for HomeAddress. if I do that then I will have to create two separate strongly typed partial views one for each address.

Any ideas on how to reuse the classes and partial views and make them dynamic and read their separate values in Action Method Post.

**Edit 1 Reply to scott-pascoe:-**

In DisplayTemplates Folder, I added following AddressModel.cshtml

```
 <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Street1);
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Street2);
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.State);
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.City);            
 </div>
```

Also In EditorTemplate Folder, I added following AddressModel.cshtml but with EditorFor

```
 <div>
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Street1);
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Street2);
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.State);
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.City);            
  </div>
```

Now how do i use them in RegisterView and also how i read values in Controller's post  Action Method ? What else would have to be modified ? I have added almost entire code above. I am pretty beginner to MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical ASP.NET MVC method for doing this is to use EditorTemplates and DisplayTemplates for your custom types.

In ~/Views/Shared, Create two folders, `DisplayTemplates`, and `EditorTemplates`.
In the DisplayTemplates folder create a partial view with the name of your Model, ie (AddressModel), and create a `DisplayFor` Template.

In the EditorTemplates folder create another partial view named `AddressModel.cshtml` and create an `EditorFor` Template.

MVC will then automatically use your templates and give you the data that you are asking for.

Comment: Please look at my Edit 1 Reply to scott-pascoe.Please let me know what else needs to be done.

Comment: @marcind,Please take a look at this one?

Comment: Thanks ..i realized it now that EditorFor Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Html.EditorFor  (or @Html.DisplayFor, for display) in your view:

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.RegisterModel
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
 {
  <div id="form">
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.HomeAddress)
      @Html.EditorFor(m => MailAddress)  
  </div>
 }
```

You will not need to have a separate controller action for the parts, just populate the addresses in the RegisterModel before in your controller.  Like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register() // this will be the page people see first
{
    var model = new RegisterModel();
    return View(model);  // assuming your view is called Register.cshtml
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model){
    DosomethingWithHomeAddress(model.HomeAddress);
    DosomethingWithMailAddress(model.MailAddress);
    model.IsSaved = true; // some way to let the user knwo that save was successful;
                          // if this is true, display a paragraph on the view
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I aprreciate your answer. I am being silly as i told i am naive in mvc. I didnt get this part  model.HomeAddress = GetAddress(...call a method to get the home address..); I just want to pass the data from Registration Form back to HttpPost method so what code i would write in GetAddress of HttpGet ?

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake, I thought you might have the address to read from somewhere if you edit it.  If you don't, you just need to create the model. :)

Comment: ,I still didnt get it when you say that i just need to create the model. Can you please modify your answer ?

Comment: Ok, I took out the confusing lines.

Comment: that didnt helped. Thanks for the trying though.